# Why does Perl give this warning?

Tags: perl

When I run my .pl file, it gives this warning - "Found = in conditional, should be == " for the  following code:

```
{local $"="\n\n" and print "My Array:\n@MyArr\n";}
```

But this warning disappears when I remove the "and" and write this:

```
{local $"="\n\n"; print "My Array:\n@MyArr\n";}
```

Any guess why does this happen? Why does Perl wants it to be == rather than = , and why does this warning disappear when I simply remove the "and" keyword?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function of `and` is to compare boolean truth values.  An assignment in a boolean context is frequently an error (people write `if $a=$b` when they mean `if $a==$b`) so `warnings` issues a message for this.

If you really genuinely want to `print` only if `"\n\n"` evaluates to true, you can use `&&` instead of `and`; but from your example, the semicolon makes much more sense.

Comment: that's true for the if statement. but here, i am using the special variable - $" that decides what would be the default separator for elements of array. and i want it to be "\n\n", so i write $"="\n\n"
what i don't understand is that both give the same output, but one gives warning. Perl take the "and" as compare operator and throws a warning, but executes it as a keyword to join two commands..

Comment: No, it is neither a comparator nor an unconditional joiner. `'' and 1` evaluates to `''` because the truth value of the empty string is false. Similarly, `$"="" and print "moo"` will never `print` because the assignment of a non-true value is also false in a boolean context. You want a semicolon, or perhaps the colon operator, although that, too, has some pesky caveats.

Comment: Yeah you are right! It doesn't print "moo". Got your point.. Thanks! :)